# How can I change the library path of an executable after it has been built/installed?

Tags: cmake

Let's say I build `myTest` with cmake. `myTest` uses `/opt/path1/lib/lib.so` at compile and link time. After running it a few times I decide that I want `myTest` to now use `/opt/path2/lib.so` (same lib name, same interfaces, just different path).

This might be cause I want to temporarily test changes to lib.so without affecting others that might be using it. I also may not have the source to `myTest` but know that it uses lib.so.

If I used a Makefile and used regular gnu/g++ make I can make this happen by setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH in the local folder. CMake ignores LD_LIB_PATH - so how do I make this happen?

Comment: "CMake ignores LD_LIBRARY_PATH" - What do you mean by "ignore"? If you are about loading the library at runtine, then it is `ldd` who loads the library, not a CMake. What CMake does, it embeds RPATH into executable when builds it. But this is done only by default, and you may change that - set [CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/variable/CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH.html) variable to TRUE.

Comment: I read somewhere that changing LD_LIBRARY_PATH has no effect on an executable built by CMake. I could be completely mistaken about this of course...

Here's what I did now

In file `common_defs.cmake` I included

`SET(CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH, true)`

Then after I built an executable I did an ldd on the built file

`lib.so => /path1`

I ran export `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path2`

and it had no effect

Comment: CMake doesn't use comma as arguments separator. Proper variable's setting is: `SET(CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH  true)`.

Comment: That did it, thanks! Could you please post your comment as the answer so that I can mark it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For find a library at runtime, ldd uses (among other things) **RPATH** directories, embedded into the executable.

By **default**, when build the executable/library, CMake adds to RPATH directories, where linked libraries are located.

E.g., when link with library `/opt/path1/lib/lib.so`, CMake adds directory `/opt/path1/lib` to RPATH. So `ldd` always finds `lib.so` library as `/opt/path1/lib/lib.so`.

For tell CMake to **not set RPATH**, set [CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/variable/CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH.html) variable:

```
set(CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH TRUE)
```

After that, `ldd` will search `lib.so` in directory, listed in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.